# mload with bigint column in informatica mapping

Tags: teradata, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Does anyone build a mapping with mload as connection and one of the column of source and target table (teradata DB) has datatype as bigint.? I am getting precision float error.

Comment: Please share the error .. and your source and target  details .

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).